# Failure in running CUDA sample after cuda 8.0 installation

Tags: ubuntu, cuda, installation

I installed the cuba8.0 on ubuntu 16 by following the steps on http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#axzz4aZ4Q3q7v

Then execute the confirmation measurement. After that, I run the make and bump into erros like the following.

$make

...

nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning). /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnvcuvid

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Makefile:381: recipe for target 'cudaDecodeGL' failed

make[1]: *** [cudaDecodeGL] Error 1

make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/cocadas/Workspace/NVIDIA_CUDA-8.0_Samples/3_Imaging/cudaDecodeGL'

Makefile:52: recipe for target '3_Imaging/cudaDecodeGL/Makefile.ph_build' failed make: *** [3_Imaging/cudaDecodeGL/Makefile.ph_build] Error 2

Then, I checked the information of the system

Environment $ printenv PATH /usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/home/cocadas/Program/android-studio/bin

$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64

OS $ uname -m x86_64

$ uname -r 4.4.0-64-generic

Others

$ lspci |grep -i nvidia 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107GLM [Quadro K1100M] (rev a1)

$ gcc --version

gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609 Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc. This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. $ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) [sudo] password for cocadas: Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done linux-headers-4.4.0-64-generic is already the newest version (4.4.0-64.85). linux-headers-4.4.0-64-generic set to manually installed. The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required: linux-headers-4.4.0-53 linux-headers-4.4.0-53-generic linux-image-4.4.0-53-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 99 not upgraded.

$ cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module 375.26 Thu Dec 8 18:36:43 PST 2016 GCC version: gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)

$ nvcc -V nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation Built on Tue_Jan_10_13:22:03_CST_2017 Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.61

So, what else can I try?

Comment: For the particular example/compile error you have shown here, [this](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/769578/cuda-setup-and-installation/cuda-6-5-cannot-find-lnvcuvid/) may be of interest.

Comment: Thanks. You point me to the right direction

Answer (score 2):

The root cause is the linker can't find libnvcuvid and driver version of make file shall be 375 (as shown in the post). Therefore, use the following command in the folder

```
~/NVIDIA_CUDA-8.0_Samples/$find . -type f -execdir sed -i 's/UBUNTU_PKG_NAME = "nvidia-367"/UBUNTU_PKG_NAME = "nvidia-375"/g' '{}' \;
```