# How to build CUDA 8 samples with gcc 5?

Tags: ubuntu, cuda

I have installed the `cuda-samples-8-0` package on Ubuntu 17.04, and I will would like to build the samples with `gcc-5`, which I have installed along `gcc-6` on my machine. gcc-6` is not supported by CUDA 8 and gives numerous compilation errors.

How to get `make` to use `gcc-5`?

I have tried `sudo make CXX=g++-5 CC=gcc-5` from the `/usr/local/cuda-8.0/samples` directory which still leads to `gcc-6` being used.

```
#error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 5 are not supported!

  ^~~~~
```

Comment: There is nvcc option of `-ccbin` to select good compiler. But there is no env string to make the selection of correct gcc global: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44792397 Or try to comment out the error-generating pragma: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/GeForce-GTX-1080,---CUDA-8.0,---Ubuntu-16.04,---Caffe Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622454

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just got this to work by symlinking `/usr/bin/gcc-5` to `/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin/gcc` and `/usr/bin/g++-5` to `/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin/g++`:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-5 /usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin/gcc
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++-5 /usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin/g++
```

And I also had to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42699624/58866) after getting the error `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnvcuvid`

Answer (score 3):

Messing up with the links can result in unwanted problems. For eg. I couldn't compile programs because they were meant for g++-7/gcc-7. I suggest using

`cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc-5 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-5 ..`

as it will not mess with your symlinks.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622454/cuda-incompatible-with-my-gcc-version but it wasnt working how I wanted. Your recommendation helped me install gpu support with xgboost